# Заменить все URL, кроме... (регулярное выражение)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Данный код заменяет все ссылки на слово `URL`. Подскажите, как внести сайт `www.super.com` в исключения, чтобы его не затрагивало регулярное выражение?

```
$text = 'Just links: www.super.com, www.example.com, http://example.com, https://example.com, http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com.';
$pattern = '#https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?\w+(?:\.\w+)+|www\.\w+(?:\.\w+)+#';
echo preg_replace($pattern, 'URL', $text);
```

[image]

Посмотреть код: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04bfd21b7d155d625510c3a0e63ca8531cb94471

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
preg_replace('~(?:https?://(?:www\.)?+|www\.)(?!super\.com\b)\w+(?:\.\w+)+~', 'URL', $s)
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/ecrlfb/3)

**Подробности**

- `(?:https?://(?:www\.)?+|www\.)` - одно из двух:

  - `https?://(?:www\.)?+` - `http`, 1 или 0 `s`, `://` и необязательная подстрока `www.`
  - `|` - или
  - `www\.` - `www.`
- `(?!super\.com\b)` - сразу справа не должно быть `super.com`, за которым нет букв, цифр и `_`
- `\w+` - 1+ букв, цифр и `_`
- `(?:\.\w+)+` - 1 и более повторов `.` + 1+ букв, цифр и `_`.

Comment: спасибо, а можете объяснить, почему это выражение «съедает» адрес с приставкой `https://www.super.com`?

Comment: @caboke Это из-за квантификатора `?`, его надо сделать сверхжадным, чтобы опциональный `www.` после `https?://` не разрешал бэктрекинг, если блок предварительного просмотра не проходит проверку.